# Invoke-RestMethod : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive

Tags: powershell

I'm facing an issue while using Invoke-RestMethod cmdlet with one URI. The error I'm getting is "Invoke-RestMethod : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive."
I have added below code to the script, as suggested in some forums, which didn't help me to resolve the issue. Could someone please help?

```
add-type @"
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
public class TrustAllCertsPolicy : ICertificatePolicy {
public bool CheckValidationResult(
ServicePoint srvPoint, X509Certificate certificate,
WebRequest request, int certificateProblem) {
return true;
}
}
"@
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = New-Object TrustAllCertsPolicy
```

Thanks in advance,
Vino Jose